# XML Serialization, como fazer

Tags: c#, xml, serialização

Preciso gerar os XML no padrão TISS da ANS.
Peguei os schemas disponíveis no [site](http://www.ans.gov.br/prestadores/tiss-troca-de-informacao-de-saude-suplementar/padrao-tiss-abril-2017), e pelo `xsd2Code` gerei as classes do tissV3_03_02.

Instanciei um objeto do tipo `ctm_guiaLote` e agora preciso gerar um XML desse objeto.

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
 XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ctm_guiaLote));
 System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream("F:\\GuiaTeste.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
 xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, lote.getlote());
 stream.Close();
```

e estou tendo a seguinte exceção, dentre outras:

> Exception:Thrown: "O tipo TISS.ItemChoiceType1 não possui o valor de enumeração 'Item' para o elemento 'Item' do espaço para nome ''." (System.InvalidOperationException)
>   A System.InvalidOperationException was thrown: "O tipo TISS.ItemChoiceType1 não possui o valor de enumeração 'Item' para o elemento 'Item' do espaço para nome ''."
>   Time: 31/07/2017 12:21:03
>   Thread:[4416]

E várias outras assim:

> "Erro ao refletir Tipo / Propriedade"
>
> Exception:Thrown: "Erro ao refletir propriedade 'Item'." (System.InvalidOperationException)
>   A System.InvalidOperationException was thrown: "Erro ao refletir propriedade 'Item'."
>   Time: 31/07/2017 12:21:03
>   Thread:[4416]

Classe ctm_guiaLote:

```
public partial class ctm_guiaLote
{

    private string numeroLoteField;

    private ctm_guiaLoteGuiasTISS guiasTISSField;

    public ctm_guiaLote()
    {
        this.guiasTISSField = new ctm_guiaLoteGuiasTISS();
    }

    public string numeroLote
    {
        get
        {
            return this.numeroLoteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.numeroLoteField = value;
        }
    }

    public ctm_guiaLoteGuiasTISS guiasTISS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.guiasTISSField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.guiasTISSField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

classe ctm_guiaLoteGuiasTISS:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ctm_spsadtGuia))]
public partial class ctm_guiaLoteGuiasTISS
{

    private List<object> itemsField;

    public ctm_guiaLoteGuiasTISS()
    {
        this.itemsField = new List<object>();
    }

    public List<object> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Código getLote():

```
    public ctm_guiaLote getlote()
    {
        ctm_guiaLote lote = new ctm_guiaLote();
        lote.numeroLote = "1";
        lote.guiasTISS = new ctm_guiaLoteGuiasTISS();

        List<object> guias = new List<object>();

        ctm_spsadtGuia guia = new ctm_spsadtGuia();
        guia.cabecalhoGuia.registroANS = "1";
        guia.cabecalhoGuia.numeroGuiaPrestador = "1";

        guia.dadosAtendimento.indicacaoAcidente = dm_indicadorAcidente.Item0;
        guia.dadosAtendimento.tipoConsulta = dm_tipoConsulta.Item1;

        guia.dadosSolicitacao.caraterAtendimento = dm_caraterAtendimento.Item1;
        guia.dadosSolicitacao.dataSolicitacao = DateTime.Now;
        guia.dadosSolicitacao.indicacaoClinica = "Teste";

        guia.dadosExecutante.CNES = "123";
        guia.dadosExecutante.contratadoExecutante.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType1.cnpjContratado;
        guia.dadosExecutante.contratadoExecutante.Item = "11111111111111";
        guia.dadosExecutante.contratadoExecutante.nomeContratado = "Contratado";

        guia.dadosSolicitante.contratadoSolicitante.nomeContratado = "Solicitante";
        guia.dadosSolicitante.contratadoSolicitante.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType1.cpfContratado;
        guia.dadosSolicitante.contratadoSolicitante.Item = "11111111111";

        guia.dadosAutorizacao.dataAutorizacao = DateTime.Now;
        guia.dadosAutorizacao.numeroGuiaOperadora = "2";
        guia.dadosAutorizacao.senha = "54321";

        guia.dadosBeneficiario.atendimentoRN = dm_simNao.N;
        guia.dadosBeneficiario.nomeBeneficiario = "Paciente";
        guia.dadosBeneficiario.numeroCarteira = "9999";
        guia.dadosBeneficiario.numeroCNS = "12345678901234";

        guia.procedimentosExecutados.Add(new ct_procedimentoExecutadoSadt() { dataExecucao = DateTime.Now, procedimento = new ct_procedimentoDados() { codigoProcedimento = "1", codigoTabela= dm_tabela.Item22, descricaoProcedimento = "Consulta" } });

        guias.Add(guia);

        lote.guiasTISS.Items = guias;

        return lote;
    }
```

Quem puder ajudar com essas exceções, muito obrigado.

Comment: Qual o código de `lote.getlote()` ?

Comment: @Renan apenas retorna um objeto `ctm_guiaLote` com alguns dados de testes preenchidos, adicionei ele também à pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito ter resolvido o problema:

Apaguei a classe gerada pelo `xsd2Code` e refiz pela linha de comando, utilizando a ferramenta `xsd.exe` com o seguinte comando:

```
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>xsd /c D:\SchemasTiss\xmldsig-core-schema.xsd D:\SchemasTiss\tissAssinaturaDigital_v1.01.xsd D:\SchemasTiss\tissV3_03_02.xsd  /o:d:\schemastiss\
```

Onde:

> D:\SchemasTiss\ Diretório onde estavam os XSD
>
> /c parâmetro para gerar classes
>
> /o: especificar diretório de saída

Esquemas:

> D:\SchemasTiss\xmldsig-core-schema.xsd
>
> D:\SchemasTiss\tissAssinaturaDigital_v1.01.xsd
>
> D:\SchemasTiss\tissV3_03_02.xsd

O restante do código, permaneceu igual e consegui gerar o xml corretamente.